# postgres installation on server with Movable Type

Tags: php, linux, postgresql, movabletype

I have just started a LAPP machine from Amazon ec2. I have updated it to be Movable Type ready. I am using the postgresql database. I stopped at the database installation section because I was getting a postgresql error. I thought the only user by default is 'postgre' and has no password. I put that in MT and it complains that I don't have a password. So I thought I need to make a new user. So I tried createuser and it is asking for a Password. I then did sudo and was now root. It still wants a Password. I do not know what it is.

Looking at the log it appears postgresql is shutdown. When I try to restart it by using pg_ctl it says I cannot be root to restart it. So I exit and run it again as the default user name it gives me and I get a permission error.

When I try to be root and createuser or do psql it says I need to give a password. I have tried to just hit return, and a bunch of other passwords that it may be. No luck. I thought since I was root I should be good.

I know postgresql is there because MT says it is.

So I need to either come up with a psql Password or be able to login as a different user with the ability to restart postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

When you are 'root', you could su to the postgres user. Then you should be able to create a new user. Remember to add the connection rights to the user in the /etc/postgresql//main/pg_hba.conf.

Comment: Doing: su - postgres allows me to restart the postgresql server. I cannot find the pg_hba.conf file.

Comment: What system are you using and how did you install postgresql?

Comment: Ubuntu linux... I installed Amazon ec2 AMI ID: ami-2203f14b . That is supposed to be postgresql. Then Movable Type says I needed DBI (version >= 1.21) and DBD::Pg (version >= 1.32) so I installed those two. Movable type is now happy and says it is installed.

Comment: pg_hba.conf was the issue. I had to uncomment the localhost and port in the file and change it to trust the local connection

Comment: Where did you find the pg_hba.conf in your installation?